# Mail template encoding suddenly wrong. Only rewrite manually works it seems. Some tips, knowledge?

Tags: php, email, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem with our E-Mail templates.
They worked fine until 2-3 days ago i have no idea what happened.

They should be utf8 encoded and get shown correctly in PHP Storm they look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
    ....
}
</style
</head>
<body>
    <center>Content with unique characters like ěäüß</center>
</body>
</html>
```

But in the Email the output is completely rubbish:
VaÅ¡e zakÃ¡zka etc.

I use the output buffer to get the template content and send it with PHPMailer.
There is no encoding anywhere but shouldn't be needed.
I tried utf8-encode/decode etc. It makes everything only worse.
The only thing that worked is to use tools like this  http://www.percederberg.net/tools/text_converter.html
to convert the plain text into utf-8 and then the code looks like rubbish like in the mail output, but then you can manually correct every character.. that worked for some templates like in german with some äüß.... but in the Czech template you have to rewrite every single character.

Is there something that i missed?  Something that i could try?

Comment: did you confirm that EVERYTHING in your system is utf? db connection? db tables? any charset mismatches anywhere will corrupt stuff.

Comment: This is so strange, there is no db connection.
PHPStorm is UTF8 too... maybe some derp edited it with some wrong encoding... is there any way to correct it outside of manually doing it so?

Answer (score 0):

I used htmlentities() on the text parts of the templates and worked quite decent!

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
    ....
}
</style
</head>
<body>
    <center><?php echo htmlentities("Content with unique characters like ěäüß"); ?></center>
</body>
```

Hope this helps someone!